# How to draw radius of a circular point buffer using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, sql

I have generated circular buffers of points in a shapefile. The generated circles and points share a common ID/key, say `pt_id`.

My question is

Is it possible to use PostGIS to generate a third layer of polylines (straight lines) representing the radii as follows?

I need this for better presentation.

[image]

Comment: @Scro I've accepted your answer since it looks right to me. Sorry, I just didn't have time to set up the environment to verify it on my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to dump the buffer points in a subquery.  I *think* the order is guaranteed, so just use `LIMIT 1` to grab the first point.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
  pt_id,
  ST_MakeLine(tp.geom, (
    SELECT 
      (ST_DumpPoints(the_geom)).geom "tb_geom"
    FROM
      the_buffer_table "tb"
    WHERE
      tb.pt_id = tp.pt_id
    LIMIT 1
    )
  ) "the_geom"
FROM
  the_point_table "tp"
```

There are multiple ways to set your buffer distance (constant, attribute, subquery, using a function, etc.), this method should work no matter how they were generated.

This is a useful concept, even if you don't want to draw the lines, because it provides a solid anchor for radius (or other) labels.

Answer (score 0):

If they can all be the same, how about something along these lines:

```
 ST_MakeLine(points.geom, 
             ST_MakePoint(ST_X(points.geom)+bufferwidth, ST_Y(points.geom))
            )
```

Depending on your SRID you may need to wrap the point constructor in a `ST_SetSRID` call and pre-convert the buffer radius into a compatible value.